# Is there a more elegant way of finding minimum in array in this case?

Tags: python, python-3.x

What needs to be done in this task:

Determine the amount of couples of neighbouring elements in which both of the numbers are multiple of 7 and also determine a minimal sum of the elements of such couples.

In the actual task I need to read a file, but here I put elements in the list by myself.

```
a = [7, 14, 2, 6, 5, 7, 7]

counter = 0
minSum = 1000000000000000000000 # This is what this question is all about
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] % 7 == 0 and a[i + 1] % 7 == 0:
        counter += 1
        if (a[i] + a[i + 1]) < minSum:
            minSum = a[i] + a[i + 1]

print(counter, minSum)
```

So my question is basically this: **is there a more elegant way of searching a minimal sum of elements, I mean without setting a giant number to the variable?**

Comment: Usually you'd use one of the system-supplied constants. In this case, it's `math.inf`.

Comment: @Ouroborus wow good way of doing this. I find Python more and more elegant day by day

Comment: Beside the point, but this code doesn't work. `range(len(a))` should be `range(len(a)-1)`.

Comment: @wjandrea it does for some reason. I noticed this mistake too after posting this question. I even asked a question afterwards where I ask why doesn't index out of range error occur

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `float('inf')`, which will always compare larger to any other number (except `float('inf')` and `float('nan')`, of course).

So:

```
minSum = float('inf')
```

Answer (score 0):

It is far more elegant to use the built-in function `min` to search for a minimum.

```py
min_sum = min(
    x + y
    for (x, y) in zip(a, a[1:])
    if x % 7 == 0 and y % 7 == 0 
)
```

Comment: That's what I thought first myself, but what about the count?

Comment: @wjandrea In that case, you can do something like `pairs = [(x, y) for ... if ...]` and then `len(pairs)` gives you the count, and `min(x + y for x, y in pairs)` gives you the minimum sum. The question only asked how to get the minimum *"without setting a giant number to the variable"*, so I only addressed that.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`itertools.pairwise`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise) to iterate through successive pairs of values and then find the minimum of valid candidates:

```py
>>> import itertools
>>> min(sum(p) for p in pairwise(a) if p[0] % 7 == 0 and p[1] % 7 == 0)
14
```

Comment: Worth mentioning this was added in Python 3.10

Comment: I thought of something similar myself, but what about the count?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `None` as a [sentinel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value):

```
counter = 0
minSum = None
for i in range(len(a)-1):
    if a[i] % 7 == 0 and a[i+1] % 7 == 0:
        counter += 1
        t = a[i] + a[i+1]
        if minSum is None or t < minSum:
            minSum = t
```

(By the way, `range(len(a))` should be `range(len(a)-1)`, which I've fixed here.)